# Trouble with C and C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I'm having a problem trying to convert a 32 bit product into a 64 bit product.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and the code is in C and C++. I would like anyone to look at the following two lines of code, one from a C source file and the other from a C++ source file.  Both of these files are included in a DLL.  I also include the disassembly of both lines of code.

**ewxlcom.c**

```
memcpy(pCM->pSecAccInfo->spUserID,userSecurityInfo.spUserID,
     sizeof(UserID));
000000000EF33BB9  mov         r8d,80h 
000000000EF33BBF  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rsp+828h] 
000000000EF33BC7  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+1F8h] 
000000000EF33BCF  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx+0BDEh] 
000000000EF33BD6  call        memcpy (0EF40352h)
```

**tcputil.cpp**

```
memcpy(serv_temp+INIT_MSG_USERID_OFFSET, pCM->pSecAccInfo->spUserID, INIT_MSG_USERID_LEN);
000000000EF3B8E6  lea         rcx,[rsp+67h] 
000000000EF3B8EB  mov         r8d,80h 
000000000EF3B8F1  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rsp+3B0h] 
000000000EF3B8F9  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rdx+0CBEh] 
000000000EF3B900  call        memcpy (0EF40352h)
```

As you can see, the first line copies some bytes into the memory pointed to by `pCM->pSecAccInfo->spUserID`.  And the second line copies those same bytes into another place in memory.  The ASM `memcpy` copies bytes from memory pointed to by register `rdx` to memory pointed to by register `rcx`.  So in the first line a value is moved into register `rcx`. This I have verified to point to `pCM`.  Then the value pointed to by `rcx + 0BDEh` is copied into `rcx`.  And the `memcpy` is called.  This works.

But later on in the second line a value is loaded into register `rdx`.  This I have verified to also point to the same `pCM` as in the first line.  It then loads the pointer residing in memory that is offset from `pCM` (`rdx`) by `0CBEh`.  That memory is all zeros, so `memcpy` crashes.

The question is why would the compiler produce different code for the same source variable. I think its an alignment problem. Is it the difference between a C file and a C++ file?  Does VS use the same compiler for both C and C++?  Are there any other things I should be looking at?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of VC++? For all we know this is a codegen issue in the compiler that has since been fixed. :-]

Comment: Are these debug builds or optimized? Maybe you can show the structure of whatever `pCM` points to?

Comment: Also, it seems strange that there are two redirections in `pCM->pSecAccInfo->spUserID`, but the assembly code seems to only perform one (in each example).  For example, in your first assembly snippet the first load to `rcx` presumably is loading `pCM` from a local stack variable into the register, then next load of `rcx` would be loading `pSecAccInfo` - but `rcx` should have `spUserID` in `rcx` before calling `memcpy()`. It's possible that with optimizations,the first load is actually `pSecAccInfo` (but you say that you verified that it's `pCM`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're linking C & C++ code, you might need to be careful about different padding characteristics in your structs.  Perhaps create a temporary function to print the offsets of each member of the struct, and copy that same code from a C source file (where you wrote it) to a C++ source file.  The two copies of the functions can remain the same, since the C++ one will be mangled, but I'd add a printf() at the top of each to say which version it is.  Then call each one from somewhere before the crash so you can compare the offsets.  If they're different, you'll need to look into compiler flags to fix that problem.  OR... perhaps you need to add lines like this...

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
 .
 .    ...your struct definitions & variables go here...
 .
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

...around your struct definitions to get the C++ side to have the same padding behavior as the C side of your project.